# Speed limit to air travel?

Tags: aerodynamics, speed, aircraft

Is there a hard limit on the speed of air travel on earth? That is, if you consider the way the human body reacts to gravity. 
Is there active research ongoing in this area?

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a hard limit on the speed of air travel on earth?**

Well, there's $v \ll c$

There is a practical problem in finding materials that can withstand the heating produced by frictional forces. Obviously this depends on altitude as well as velocity. You  could look up the velocities of meteors - they are below 42 Km/s (94,000 MPH). For manned vehicles, typical low earth orbit re-entry speeds are near 7.8 Km/s (17,500 MPH). The problems limiting velocity are your needs to remain within the atmosphere and to avoid incineration.

> **if you consider the way the human body reacts to gravity**

No need to worry about that. At a constant velocity the human body feels no additional force so long as the vehicle maintains its integrity. The problem is that the atmosphere of Earth is not planar so a very fast moving vehicle would have to introduce some additional centripetal acceleration to remain in the atmosphere for long.

> **Is there active research ongoing in this area?**

I'd be surprised if there were any reason to fund or conduct such research. The fastest manned aircraft are military aircraft and trends seem to be away from using human crew.

---

### What if ...

There are good reasons why anyone researching this subject would not employ practical experimentation.

See http://what-if.xkcd.com/1/